# Spring JPA Multi-column inner join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, inner-join

I'm still new with spring JPA and i'm facing a problem trying to do an inner join with 2 columns on an entity

i have these tables

```
CREATE TABLE event (
id bigint unsigned auto_increment primary key comment 'id of the event',
user_id bigint unsigned not null comment 'id of the user',
organizer_id bigint unsigned not null comment 'id of the organizer user'
);

CREATE TABLE user (
id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'user id',
email VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL COMMENT 'user email',
name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COMMENT  'user name',
surname VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'user surname'
)
```

where event.user_id and event.organizer_id maps to the user.id

I also have these entities mapping those tables

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Event> events;
}

@Entity
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "organizer_id", nullable = false)
    private User organizer;
}
```

The idea is to get in the List of the user all the events of the user where the user id is mapped by user_id or organizer_id on events table.

I have tried to use multiple @joinColumn annotations (and removing the mappedBy from the @manyToOne() but i hit this error:

org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering has the wrong number of column. should be 1

The only solution i have found is getting it in other List so to use, but i'm sure i'm missing the correct way of doing it as it should be a very common use case.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: A side note: It is recommended to use `Long` instead of `long` for your ID type, since it distinguishes between `null` (not yet assigned) and 0 (which might be a valid value).

Comment: that's true, didn't thought about that. I'll change it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm just using a ```return repository.findById(id).orElse(null);``` to get the User with all the data on it

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is to get in the List of the user all the events of the user where the user id is mapped by user_id or organizer_id on events table.

JPA is a representation of an entity in the database, your requirement needs post-processing after you retrieve what is in the database.

> I'm missing the correct way of doing it as it should be a very common use case.

It is not a very common use case to "merge" two different relationships onto a single collection at the JPA level.

So, a way of doing that:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Event> userEvents;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organizer")
    private List<Event> organizerEvents;
}
```